# How to pass Javascript properties correctly such that they can be modified by a function

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, javascript-objects, pass-by-reference

I understand that JavaScript objects, including arrays, are automatically passed by reference, so I have something like this:

```
class Thing {
    constructor( ) {
        this.letters = [ "A", "B" ];
        this.numbers = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

        this.change( this.letters, this.numbers );
    }

    change( _letters, _numbers ) {
        let l = _letters;
        let n = _numbers;

        l = [ ];
        n = 6;
    }
}

var t = new Thing( );
console.log( t );
```

The log request shows that there has been no change to the properties of *Thing*. And yet, under different conditions that I can not recognise, I have accidentally modified passed parameters inside a function, and have had to use something like `n = Array.from( _numbers )` to avoid modifying the source property. *Would someone be able to explain what is happening, and why?*

I would like to pass object properties by reference such that I can modify more than one related property in a single function call, and thereby reserve the return value for debugging purposes.

Thank you.

Comment: Your example is not modifying the objects, you are just reassigning the variables. You would have to have accessed some property to modify the object, eg `_letters[1] = 'C'` or `l[1] = 'C'`

Comment: With @PatrickEvans, on the first two lines of `change()`, `l` and `n` are references to your class's properties. However, on the next two lines, you reassign those variables to now be references to an empty array and 6. `l` and `n` no longer reference your class's properties, they now reference values declared in the scope of `change()`.

Comment: @DylanLandry: Thank you. That makes complete sense. How, then, would we typically (or in best practice) modify the objects passed? Is it only through references (e.g. _letters[1] ) and iteration that we can change the original values?

Comment: @DylanLandry Well, no, `l` and `n` are not references. All they do is *hold* the same object reference as the `this.letters` and `this.numbers` properties respectively.

Comment: @POD There is no pass-by-reference in JavaScript. There is passing of reference values though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the scoping. When you declared with `let`, the declaration is scoped to the function `change` and you are also reassigning the block-scoped variables here:

```
l = [ ];
n = 6;
```

If you want to change the class properties, you can do:

```
change(_letters, _numbers) {
    this.letters = _letters; // `this` scoped to class
    this.numbers = _numbers; // `this` scoped to class
  }
```

See the example:

```js
// simple demo start
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];

let n = numbers;
n.push(4)
console.info(n, typeof n);

n = 6; // reassign n
console.info(n, typeof n, numbers);
// simple demo end

// refactored class
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.letters = ["A", "B"];
    this.numbers = [1, 2, 3];

    this.change(this.letters, this.numbers);
  }

  change(_letters, _numbers) {
    let l = _letters; // `let` is scoped to `change()`
    let n = _numbers; // `let` is scoped to `change()`

    l = []; // only changes scoped l
    n = 6; // only changes scoped n
  }

  changeFix(_letters, _numbers) {
    this.letters = _letters; // `this` scoped to class
    this.numbers = _numbers; // `this` scoped to class
  }
}

var t = new Thing();
console.log(t);

t.change(['C'], [4]);
console.info(t);

t.changeFix(['C'], [4]);
console.info(t);
```

Comment: You can also edit class properties from outside the class through the class instance: `i.numbers = [4,5,6];`